# Unable to access Magento2 admin panel

Tags: magento2.2

1. I am unable to access magento admin.Developer did my website non contactable,  how can I fix this issue ?
2. This problem happen every now and then,  is there a permanent to prevent it ?

**Error Msg :**

Class Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor does not exist
Error log record number: ecca7e8db973cf3753ce9ad6680707fcc9b9fe5e1b727f1283cc556bbd5d3ebd

Comment: Hi @Jaslin, Did you try it after clearing the directories generated/* var/cache/* var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* and apply the directories permissions?

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Class Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor does not exist" typically indicates an issue with code generation in Magento 2. Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve this issue:

**Clear Generated Code & Cache:**

```
generated/*
var/cache/*
var/view_preprocessed/*
```

**Recompile:**

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

**Check File Permissions:**

Ensure that the file permissions are set correctly. The web server user should have proper permissions to read and execute Magento files. You can use the following commands to set permissions:

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
```

By following these steps, you should be able to access your admin.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately,  I am not tech savvy to perform troubleshooting, do you have any idea who can I approach to assist ?  Is this a magento bug as it happen quite often.

Comment: @Jaslin, This is not a Magento bug. The directories and files permissions were reset due to some executions. To resolve this issue, we need to apply the correct permissions. Please reach out to your server team or developer to execute above commands.

Comment: Thanks ! The developer who did our website is out of business,  may I check where can I get help from ?

Comment: If you have server access then you can login to the server & find SSH. Then on SSH CLI you can run the above shared commands to the root of magento.